# Prevent Safari from collapsing children divs in a container with a max-height and a hidden overflow

Tags: html, css, sass, safari

I'm trying to create a div with a max-height that has a number of cards nested within it, it works well on Chrome and looks this way:

[image: Chrome]

However, on safari, all the children divs are collapsed to fit into the max-height, when what I really want for them is to be their normal sizes and be hidden by the "overflow : hidden" property of the parent div:

[image: Chrome]

Here are my styles, it's written in Sass:

```
&_card {
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: to-em(407);
  &_cards {
    height: inherit;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by writing this line under `&_cards`:

```
height: fit-content;
```